# displaying the right ID

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I am having trouble with this code. I am making a forum kinda thing for myself to test my skills ([looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VowZ.png)) and now I am having trouble displaying the right ID. I need the ID for something but when I test this code under here it will display me 1 same ID for every reaction. I am not sure why? Maybe the`<script>` doesnt work in a foreach? hopefully someone can help me with this problem.

```
$reacttie = $app->get_reactie($actieftopicid);
foreach ($reacttie as $reactie) {
echo '
<div class="timeline-footer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function printIt(){
     alert(document.getElementById("abcId").value);
  </script>

  <form name="formName">
    <input type=hidden id="abcId" name="abcName" value="'.$reactie['id'] .'"/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type=button value="Reageer" onclick="printIt()" />
  </form>
</div>';
```

Comment: Have you checked if the data returned from `$app->get_reactie($actieftopicid)` is correct?

Comment: HTML ids must be unique. `id="abcId"` is wrong

Answer (score 2):

It's a classic mistake: You are creating multiple elements with this same id, so `document.getElementById("abcId")` will always return You first element with this id.

Answer (score 0):

Your php part is correct, but your javascript code is wrong. Currently, you have many elements with the same id and `getElementById` only returns the first matching one. Instead, you should classes and sibling relationships or kind of.

In addition to that, you define the printIt function multiple times, which also isn't a good idea - move the function outside your loop (or event better, move the whole javascript logic into an external .js file)

In your case, there is also an easier way, just passing the id to the function:

```
$reacttie = $app->get_reactie($actieftopicid);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
   function printIt(id){
     alert(id);
  </script>';

foreach ($reacttie as $reactie) {
echo '
<div class="timeline-footer">    
  <form name="formName">
    <input type=hidden name="abcName" value="'.$reactie['id'] .'"/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type=button value="Reageer" onclick="printIt(\''.$reactie['id'] .'\')" />
  </form>
</div>';
```